Adding wireless switch to existing 3-way wired system
Can I add a wireless light switch to and existing 3 or 4-way wired system in order to add a switch in another location? I've searched for this answer extensively and I'm not getting any clear confirmation on that. I've read through countless installation instructions and FAQ's on various reputable wireless switch manufacturers and they don't address that aspect at all. Their instructions seem to be focused around buying all their products to make everything work together on a complete wireless/wifi system. I'm not looking for wifi, just a simple remote switch that works with the existing manual (3-way) switches for the same light.
There was some sort of mix up or communication breakdown with the electrician when our house was wired and we currently have no way to turn off our hall light that leads to our bedroom at the bedroom end of our hall. We have to turn it off before we walk down the hall and then proceed down the hall in complete darkness.
The biggest problem: Our hall light was wired with the stair light and the stair light is on a 4-way switch. The stair light switches are all correct. We either need to install a remote switch to turn all those lights off in the bedroom or find a simple way to separate the hall light from the stair light. Since these lights are connect through our attic and covered in insulation/vapor barrier, I'm assuming it's not the easiest to bypass the hall light and put it on a separate switch. Alternatively, can I use a wireless switch in the hall light box somehow to have it controlled separately with the power for the stair light running through the box?

There is no magic wireless system. Traditional switches - regular, 3-way and 4-way - are all based on physically connecting/disconnecting wires. Incredibly simple and reliable, switches very inexpensive, but with the catch that two or three or sometimes even four wires (not counting ground) are needed to connect each switch properly.
Some smart switches (electronic timers, wireless remotes, WiFi control, etc. - lots of varieties) when used in multiple switch circuits (a.k.a., 3-way and 4-way) require using matching devices in every switch location and then also allow a remote. Some smart switches only require one switch to be replaced and use either the existing wiring with ordinary switches or use wireless remotes. But there is no system that can use a wireless remote without replacing at least one of the existing switches.
So your solutions are generally going to be one or both of:

Rewire existing switches, possibly including running one or more new cables, depending on the particular issues, and run a cable to an additional switch for the missing switch location
Replace one or more switches with smart switches and add a compatible wireless remote

TANSTAAFL

I have found a number of products that offer a (wired) wireless switch paired with a separate remote. What I'm not certain about, was if I have to replace all switches on the same circuit or can I replace one and the other manual ones will still work in conjunction with the wireless elements. When I look up manuals and product descriptions on those products, none of them seem to address the concept of using a wireless switch in conjunction with existing manual switches. Rewiring is something we're trying to avoid as we don't want attic sealing and insulation affected for this fix.

Some, but not all, smart switches are designed so that 3-way/4-way configurations (whether any wireless switches are added to the mix or not) can be accommodated using existing ordinary switches for all locations except for one location, by doing some rewiring only in the switch boxes. Whether such a system will work for you depends on a lot of unknowns regarding specific wiring methods. There are too many ways to wire a 3-way switch to guess.

I've used a Zigbee relay for this (like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006890345915.html ).
I disconnected the live feed to the switch, and the switched live from the switch to the light, and connected them to S1/S2 terminals. Then the live and neutral connect to the power input, and the light connects to the output. The module switches the light if the switch state changes or if it gets a Zigbee command, and reports the current state of the light correctly.
Similar interfaces are available for other control types, and they actually work better for a multi-way switch than a single one (where there's a single one, it's hard to get used to the position of the switch not necessarily reflecting the current state of the light, and just flipping it if you want the state of the light to change, but that's what you expect for 2-or-more way switching)

We have some Zigbee products that we bought, but haven't utilized yet. It might be worth a try installing them for this application.

I am not exactly clear on your setup (if the light is controlled in a 3-way or 4-way configuration), but something in the Lutron Caseta family (Diva Smart Dimmer, DVRF-6L or similar) may work for you. The smart dimmer family is required if your switch boxes do not have a neutral available.  If your house is modern enough to have neutrals available at the switch box, you can probably use one of the pure-switch variants. There are an overwhelming number of options, but refer to this brochure (especially the table beginning on Page 19) to find something that works for you.
Scroll down to the Wiring Diagrams section of https://support.lutron.com/us/en/instructions/diva-dimmer-dvrf-6l, where they have diagrams for single pole, 3-way, and 4-way configurations.
The "3-way with mechanical switch" is probably what you need. You will:

Replace one of your mechanical switches in the 3-way circuit with the DVRF-6L smart switch. (Location 1 in the installation diagram below).
Adjust the wiring of the other mechanical switch (to connect it directly to the smart switch). (Location 2 in the installation diagram below)
Pair additional paddle remotes as required.

Note that this only works in a 3-way configuration (with 2 physical switches). I do not know if they have an option for 4-way configurations. You might have to replace one of the physical switches with an additional paddle remote.
You can also look at the Lutron "Wiring Wizard" for step-by-step instructions and videos: https://webtools.lutron.com/wiringwizard/us/en


There is one kind of "wireless switch" which may help your exact situation.
Install an "Occupancy sensor" or "vacancy sensor" that detects motion in your hallway via IR will allow you to walk down the hall, and have the light turn off after a configurable timeout.
This can be incredibly convenient if there's no light switch handy.
Downsides: pets and kids will set off the light too, you can't sneak around in the dark.  There's no way to make the light go off faster, and you can't leave the light on (say while someone goes to sleep).  Light can also turn itself off while you're standing there not moving.
I have a sensor like this in my garage, and it turns the lights on no matter which of the three doors I enter by.   Very handy when I come in the side outside door with a bike, or drive in the car-door too.
Is it "wireless" ?   Kind-of yes, in that you can switch it without actuating a physical switch; its your simple presence in range that does it.


If you use a wallbox-type sensor, some have manual overrides and other helpful functions (look at Lutron's products for an example)
